# Reindexing a dataframe using existing columns as a multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I currently have a pandas dataframe in this configuration

```
    col_1    col_2   col_3   col_4
0   fish     50g     3       £5
1   cheese   50g     4       £6
2   fish     100g    2       £20
3   fish     200g    2       £25
4   bread    50g     15      £50
.   ...      ...     ...     ...
```

I would like to have a dataframe in this configuration

```
             col_3  col_4
fish    50g      3     £5
       100g      2    £20
       200g      2    £25
cheese  50g      4     £6
bread   50g     15    £50
  ...   ...    ...    ...
```

I've looked at the docs at [the pandas website](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/advanced.html#advanced-hierarchical) and I've come to the conclusion that I need to use the pd.MultiIndex constructors.

However, no matter what variation of`pd.MultiIndex.constructor(df[["col_1","col_2"]])` I try, I don't get out an `m_index` object that works when I try to use it as `pd.DataFrame(df,index=m_index)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're looking for `df.set_index(['col_1', 'col_2'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), but for correct sorting is necessary remove last char `g` from column `col_2` and cast by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `int` (or `float`). Last you can add `g` and create new [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html) [`from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df['col_2'] = df['col_2'].str[:-1].astype(int)

print df.set_index(['col_1','col_2'])
              col_3  col_4
col_1  col_2              
fish   50         3      5
cheese 50         4      6
fish   100        2     20
       200        2     25
bread  50        15     50

print df.set_index(['col_1','col_2'])
        .sort_index(level=['col_1','col_2'], ascending=[False,True])

              col_3  col_4
col_1  col_2              
fish   50         3      5
       100        2     20
       200        2     25
cheese 50         4      6
bread  50        15     50
```

```
df1 = df.set_index(['col_1','col_2'])
        .sort_index(level=['col_1','col_2'], ascending=[False,True])

              col_3  col_4
col_1  col_2              
fish   50         3      5
cheese 50         4      6
fish   100        2     20
       200        2     25
bread  50        15     50

#change multiindex
new_index = zip(df1.index.get_level_values('col_1'),
                df1.index.get_level_values('col_2').astype(str) + 'g')
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_index, names = df1.index.names)
print df1
              col_3  col_4
col_1  col_2              
fish   50g        3      5
       100g       2     20
       200g       2     25
cheese 50g        4      6
bread  50g       15     50
```